# Using inttrap and diff to get the length of a curve in Scilab

Tags: math, diff, difference, scilab

How can you get the length of the curve down below between 0 and 4*pi? The commands you should use are inttrap and diff. Here is what I have now:

```
t=linspace(0,4*%pi)
x=(4+sin(a*t)).*cos(3*t)
y=(4+sin(a*t)).*sin(3*t)
z=cos(3*t)

xx=diff(x)
yy=diff(y)
zz=diff(z)
aid=sqrt(xx^2+yy^2+zz^2)
length=inttrap([t],aid)
```

Getting error message, the last step is not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for error message is that `t` and `aid` have different sizes. And that is because `diff` returns a vector with 1 entry fewer than the input. You can see how it works on an example: `diff([3 1 5])` is `[-2 4]`.

To fix this, use `t(1:$-1)`, which omits the last entry of `t`.  That is,

```
len = inttrap(t(1:$-1), aid)
```

(Please don't use `length`, which is a function name in Scilab.)

Another problem you have is that `diff` is just differences, not a derivative. To get the derivative, you need to divide by the step size, which in your case is `t(2)-t(1)`.

Also, the syntax `xx^2` is deprecated for elementwise power; use `xx.^2` instead

```
t = linspace(0,4*%pi)
a = 1
x = (4+sin(a*t)).*cos(3*t)
y = (4+sin(a*t)).*sin(3*t)
z = cos(3*t)

step = t(2)-t(1)
xx = diff(x)/step
xy = diff(y)/step
xz = diff(z)/step
aid = sqrt(xx.^2+yy.^2+zz.^2)
len = inttrap(t(1:$-1), aid)
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is written in a good, simple way. It helped me out.